# Trying to have NMOSs in parallel while passing current through only one at a time

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, nmos, oscillation

If I wanted to have  a bias current I1 going through M1 or M2 and I want M1 to alternate between on off (M1 on/M2 off, M1 off/M2 on) would this work? I simulated this with spice and for the first cycle the nmoss have the bias current through one and none through the other but after the first cycle of the square wave they both have less than the bias current but not zero.  What would I be doing wrong? And what configuration would I need to achieve the effect I am looking for?  (Clocks go 0V-1.8V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjT7nI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Because R3 and R4 are giving negative feedback which isn't letting M1 and M2 turn all the way on. It's operating as a linear device, not a switch. The more M1 or M2 turn on, the more current flows through R3, which increases the voltage at the source pin, which (because you are driving the gate with a voltage referenced to ground) decreases the difference in voltage between the gate and source pin which turns the MOSFET off more. An equilibrium is found. Negative feedback

Comment: Swap positions of R3 with M1 and R4 with M2 so that the source pin is the same as ground so negative feedback does not happen. If this is not acceptable then use a floating gate drive so the gate voltage is referenced to the source pin voltage instead of ground, or use a PMOSFET. Using a PMOSFET in between the resistors in each leg will result in the same negative feedback situtation you have now, except R1 and R2 will be the negative feedback resistors so you will have to swap those positions as well as change the gate drive accordingly.

Comment: Per datasheet, IRF530 has a threshold voltage of between 2 and 4 V. You'll need more than a 1.8 V clock to drive those gates.

Comment: I should have included the exact model I was using, but yes, I would need to know the right Vgs. I was assuming though that for an arbitrary NMOS the clock would go up to at least Vgs, for demonstration purposes

Comment: @Toor Make that an answer, let it be marked as such for future searches.

Comment: "I should have included the exact model I was using" - yes, you should. I simulated your circuit in LTSpice using the standard NMOS part and it appears to work perfectly (current in each FET cycles between 500nA and 34.3fA). With 500nA 'bias' current the voltage drop across R3 and R4 is 0.5mV max.  "I was assuming though that for an arbitrary NMOS the clock would go up to at least Vgs" - that depends on the FET! Also at this low current the FET's capacitances could have a large effect. So, which FET model were you using?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I meant that for demonstration purposes assume the clock does go up to the required Vgs. I am sorry for the lack of clarity.  To answer your question, a 180nm model I found with a quick google (http://scale.engin.brown.edu/classes/EN1600S08/tutorials/180nm.lib)

Comment: I tried your model in LTspice. Despite several errors, warnings and ignored parameters in the model it worked. Maximum 'off' current was 784fA. Only thing of note was I had to set the square wave rise and fall times to >=3us to avoid output spikes. So both the circuit and model appear to be OK (at least in LTspice).

Comment: @BruceAbbott that is interesting about the square wave rise and fall time. That might be a problem. I plan to use this in a larger circuit where CMOS gates will drive the square waves, and I expect those to have a faster pullup/pulldown time than 3us. Would your findings confirm that what I described would not work with this NMOS model, or could there be a workaround? NOTE: I would not be using the resistors in the larger circuit, these were just for a quick test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R3 and R4 are giving negative feedback which isn't letting M1 and M2 turn all the way on. It's operating as a linear device, not a switch. The more M1 or M2 turn on, the more current flows through R3, which increases the voltage at the source pin, which (because you are driving the gate with a voltage referenced to ground) decreases the difference in voltage between the gate and source pin which turns the MOSFET off more. An equilibrium is found. Negative feedback.

Swap positions of R3 with M1 and R4 with M2 so that the source pin is the same as ground so negative feedback does not happen. If this is not acceptable (maybe if R3 and R4 are loads and you need them referenced to ground for whatever reason), then use a floating gate drive so the gate voltage is referenced to the source pin voltage instead of ground.

You could also use a PMOSFET. However, just swapping out your NMOSFETs for PMOSFETs won't work because R1 and R2 will end up acting as negative feedback resistors just like R3 and R4 did with your NMOSFETs. So you will have to swap R1 and R2 with the positions of the PMOSFETs similar to swapping positions of R3 and R4 with the NMOSFETs, except in the case of the PMOSFETs R3 and R4 will remain referenced to ground which may be desirable for various reasons if they are your loads. Note that your gate drive for the PMOSFETs will have to change as well.